# MongoDB geoJson Query to find distance between two points

Tags: angular, mongodb, api, flask, geojson

background info:

I have developed an API using Flask, and the dataset is football teams from the premier league 18-19 season, stored within MongoDB. I have also developed a frontend web-app using angular that fetches the data from the API and presents it.

My issue:

The teams collection looks like this:-

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("619fc490ce1cd47befba0518"),
    "name" : "Brighton & Hove Albion FC",
    "logo" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/f/fd/Brighton_%26_Hove_Albion_logo.svg/400px-Brighton_%26_Hove_Albion_logo.svg.png",
    "code" : "BHA",
    "country" : "England",
    "players" : [
            {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("619fc493ce1cd47befba07a4"),
                    "name" : "Barry Simms",
                    "number" : 10,
                    "position" : "Defender"
            },
            {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("619fc493ce1cd47befba07a5"),
                    "name" : "Gregory Goshay",
                    "number" : 4,
                    "position" : "Goalkeeper"
            },
            {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("619fc493ce1cd47befba07a6"),
                    "name" : "James Bowen",
                    "number" : 10,
                    "position" : "Goalkeeper"
            },
            {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("619fc493ce1cd47befba07a7"),
                    "name" : "Daniel Rivera",
                    "number" : 28,
                    "position" : "Goalkeeper"
            },
            {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("619fc493ce1cd47befba07a8"),
                    "name" : "Eugene Williams",
                    "number" : 29,
                    "position" : "Midfielder"
            },
            {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("619fc493ce1cd47befba07a9"),
                    "name" : "Clement Toone",
                    "number" : 15,
                    "position" : "Midfielder"
            },
            {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("619fc493ce1cd47befba07aa"),
                    "name" : "Daniel Johnson",
                    "number" : 21,
                    "position" : "Midfielder"
            },
            {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("619fc493ce1cd47befba07ab"),
                    "name" : "John Stewart",
                    "number" : 1,
                    "position" : "Striker"
            },
            {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("619fc493ce1cd47befba07ac"),
                    "name" : "Philip Walker",
                    "number" : 13,
                    "position" : "Midfielder"
            },
            {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("619fc493ce1cd47befba07ad"),
                    "name" : "Robert Mahoney",
                    "number" : 27,
                    "position" : "Midfielder"
            },
            {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("619fc493ce1cd47befba07ae"),
                    "name" : "Billy Dewan",
                    "number" : 24,
                    "position" : "Defender"
            },
            {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("619fc493ce1cd47befba07af"),
                    "name" : "Michael Dixon",
                    "number" : 29,
                    "position" : "Defender"
            },
            {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("619fc493ce1cd47befba07b0"),
                    "name" : "Cleveland Koualeski",
                    "number" : 3,
                    "position" : "Goalkeeper"
            },
            {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("619fc493ce1cd47befba07b1"),
                    "name" : "Floyd Rosseau",
                    "number" : 3,
                    "position" : "Defender"
            },
            {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("619fc493ce1cd47befba07b2"),
                    "name" : "Rodney Horn",
                    "number" : 11,
                    "position" : "Goalkeeper"
            }
    ],
    "stadium" : {
            "type" : "Point",
            "coordinates" : [
                    50.83120228,
                    -0.1534524
            ]
    }

{
        "_id" : ObjectId("619fc490ce1cd47befba0519"),
        "name" : "Chelsea FC",
        "logo" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/c/cc/Chelsea_FC.svg/360px-Chelsea_FC.svg.png",
        "code" : "CHE",
        "country" : "England",
        "players" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("619fc493ce1cd47befba07b3"),
                        "name" : "Felipe Ray",
                        "number" : 29,
                        "position" : "Goalkeeper"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("619fc493ce1cd47befba07b4"),
                        "name" : "Jacob Duncan",
                        "number" : 21,
                        "position" : "Defender"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("619fc493ce1cd47befba07b5"),
                        "name" : "Scott Comeaux",
                        "number" : 16,
                        "position" : "Midfielder"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("619fc493ce1cd47befba07b6"),
                        "name" : "Aaron Ellis",
                        "number" : 14,
                        "position" : "Defender"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("619fc493ce1cd47befba07b7"),
                        "name" : "Richard Pena",
                        "number" : 4,
                        "position" : "Goalkeeper"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("619fc493ce1cd47befba07b8"),
                        "name" : "Jeffrey Higgins",
                        "number" : 24,
                        "position" : "Midfielder"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("619fc493ce1cd47befba07b9"),
                        "name" : "Ray Bohlke",
                        "number" : 14,
                        "position" : "Striker"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("619fc493ce1cd47befba07ba"),
                        "name" : "George Buchanan",
                        "number" : 20,
                        "position" : "Midfielder"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("619fc493ce1cd47befba07bb"),
                        "name" : "Michael Baksh",
                        "number" : 15,
                        "position" : "Goalkeeper"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("619fc493ce1cd47befba07bc"),
                        "name" : "John Peterson",
                        "number" : 24,
                        "position" : "Defender"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("619fc493ce1cd47befba07bd"),
                        "name" : "Leon Vanauken",
                        "number" : 30,
                        "position" : "Defender"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("619fc493ce1cd47befba07be"),
                        "name" : "Gabriel Manes",
                        "number" : 13,
                        "position" : "Defender"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("619fc493ce1cd47befba07bf"),
                        "name" : "Richard Scheffel",
                        "number" : 27,
                        "position" : "Striker"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("619fc493ce1cd47befba07c0"),
                        "name" : "David Malinowski",
                        "number" : 10,
                        "position" : "Midfielder"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("619fc493ce1cd47befba07c1"),
                        "name" : "Tony Rhodes",
                        "number" : 15,
                        "position" : "Goalkeeper"
                }
        ],
        "stadium" : {
                "type" : "Point",
                "coordinates" : [
                        51.48210342,
                        -0.18913716
                ]
        } 
...
```

Basically I want a user to be able to choose two teams in the UI through two drop downs and then when the data is submitted it will perform a geoJson query that will calculate the distance between the two teams in Km, however currently I am having an issue of accessing the stadium coordinates through the UI to API.

This is my python code:

```
@app.route("/api/v1.0/stadiums", methods=["POST"])
def geoJson():

formTeams = {
    "team1": request.form["name"],
    "team2": request.form["name"],
}

for team1 in teams.find():
    team1['_id'] = str(team1['_id'])
    for team2 in teams.aggregate([
        {"$geoNear":
             {"near":
                  {"$match":
                      {"type": "Point",
                       "coordinates":
                           team1["stadium"]["coordinates"]},
                  "maxDistance": 50000000,
                  "minDistance": 1,
                  "distanceField": "distance",
                  "spherical": True
                 }
            }
        },
        {"$project": {"name": 1, "country": 1,
                      "distance": 1}},
        {"$limit": 1}
    ]):
        distance_km = str(round(team2["distance"] / 1000))

        return make_response(jsonify(distance_km), 200)
```

My front end code looks like:-
geostadium.component.html:

```
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <h2>Away day</h2>
      <form [formGroup]="addStadium" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="team1">Choose a team</label>
          <select id="team1" name="team1"
                  class="form-control"
                  formControlName="team1">
            <option *ngFor = "let team of teams_list | async">{{team.name}}</option>
          </select>
        </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="team2">Choose a team</label>
            <select id="team2" name="team2"
                    class="form-control"
                    formControlName="team2">
              <option *ngFor = "let team of teams_list | async">{{team.name}}</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        <br />
        <span> You must complete all fields</span>
        <button type="submit"
                class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-danger">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

geostadium.compomnent.ts:-

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { WebService } from './web.service';
import {ActivatedRoute} from "@angular/router";
import {FormBuilder, Validators} from "@angular/forms";


@Component({
  selector: 'geostadium',
  templateUrl: './geostadium.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./geostadium.component.css']
})
export class GeostadiumComponent {
  addStadium: any;

  constructor(private webService: WebService,
              private route: ActivatedRoute,
              private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.addStadium = this.formBuilder.group({
      team1: ['', Validators.required],
      team2: ['', Validators.required]
    })
     this.teams_list = this.webService.getTeamsID(this.route.snapshot.params['id']);

  }

 onSubmit() {
   this.webService.postStadiums(this.addStadium.value).subscribe((response: any) => {
     this.addStadium.reset();
   });
 }
```

Can anyone help me/point me in the right direction as I want to display on the UI

'X is Zkm away from Y'

Any input is appreciated - thanks everyone!

Comment: When you say `X is Zkm away from Y` do you mean driving, straight line along the Earth's surface, or at a constant altitude following a great circle?

Comment: Hi Joe, I am using 2dsphere indexes, which calculate geometries on an earth-like sphere.

Comment: ok, that sounds like constant altitude on a great circle.  Which means it will probably take a smallish number of nanoseconds to calculate that in the client browser from the lat/long.  Does that operation really need to be centralized at the database server?